# Why android app dont build in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I create my first android app in intellij idea editor but when build project get this error.

Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'TakZarf2'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
>        Required by:
>            :TakZarf2:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect

My internet connection in right.

How to solve this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: This first line explained `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.` Your  configuration in your  project is incorrect. It cannot find the library.

Comment: How to change configuration of project?

Comment: Follow the [official tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-android-development.html) or use Android Studio to save your trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a firewall issue. Please check whether the URL - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/ is accessible from a browser window.

If the above URL works on browser, check whether you have any HTTP proxy configured in IntelliJ.  This is accessible from IntelliJ=>settings=>appearance and behavior=>system settings=>http proxy.

Comment: I see number file on up link and I have not any proxy

Comment: Do you have any proxy settings in your browser? The issue is clearly related to connectivity. You can try using an alternate network for testing (like tether from your mobile).